# Printing all the possibilities of dimensions

Tags: c#

Is there any way in C# or any known library for printing all the possibilities of dimensions size, like in arrays declaration?

For example:

```
[2, 2]
```

Gives:

```
[0,0] [0,1] [0,2] [1,0] [1,1] [1,2] [2,0] [2,1] [2,2]
```

I would like it to work for all dimensions (1D, 2D, 3D, 4D...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest *generating* all the items possible

```
private static IEnumerable<String> Ranges(params int[] ranges) {
  int[] current = new int[ranges.Length];

  bool hasItems = true;

  yield return String.Format("[{0}]", String.Join(",", current));

  while (hasItems) {
    hasItems = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < current.Length; ++i) {
      if (current[i] < ranges[i]) {
        hasItems = true;

        current[i] = current[i] + 1;

        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; --j)
          current[j] = 0;

        yield return String.Format("[{0}]", String.Join(",", current));

        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Your sample:

```
 int[] source = new int[] { 2, 2 };

 // [0,0] [1,0] [2,0] [0,1] [1,1] [2,1] [0,2] [1,2] [2,2]
 Console.Write(String.Join(" ", Ranges(source)));
```

Another test (3 dimensions)

```
  int[] source = new int[] { 2, 1, 3};

  // [0,0,0] [1,0,0] [2,0,0] [0,1,0] [1,1,0] [2,1,0] [0,0,1] [1,0,1] [2,0,1] [0,1,1] 
  // [1,1,1] [2,1,1] [0,0,2] [1,0,2] [2,0,2] [0,1,2] [1,1,2] [2,1,2] [0,0,3] [1,0,3] 
  // [2,0,3] [0,1,3] [1,1,3] [2,1,3]
  Console.Write(String.Join(" ", Ranges(source)));
```

**Edit**: if you want to work with actual multidimension array, you can use *Linq* to obtain array of dimensions:

```
  // d is 3D array
  // please, notice, that type of the array (string) doesn't play any role
  string[,,] d = new string[2, 3, 1];

  // array of dimensions: int[] {2, 3, 1}
  int[] dims = Enumerable
    .Range(0, d.Rank)
    .Select(dim => d.GetLength(dim))
    .ToArray();

  Console.Write(String.Join(" ", Ranges(dims)));
```

Comment: Just be aware 107MP, if you use this, your instructor will know *for sure* that you didn't write it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I wasnt asking for solution. But I though It would be harder to do. I appreciate your effort.

Comment: @BradleyUffner that's not a homework ;)

Comment: @107MP but this is always a one-dimensional array. didn't you ask for multidimensional arrays?

Comment: @M. Schena: nice catch! Thank you! In case of *actual array*, one should obtain the *array of dimensions*; it can be done via Linq. See my edit.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: you are so skillful with linq. nice solution. and I'm still working with for-loops like in my solution underneath; that's why i like SO, learning so much!

Answer (score 2):

A little IEnumerable magic!

```
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GetCombinations(IEnumerable<int> dimensions)
    {
        if (!dimensions.Any())
        {
            yield return Enumerable.Empty<int>();
            yield break;
        }

        var first = dimensions.First();

        foreach (var subSolution in GetCombinations(dimensions.Skip(1)))
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < first + 1; i++)
            {
                yield return new[] { i }.Concat(subSolution);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution which generates the index outputs dynamically from any multidimensional array:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[,] arr = new int[2, 2];
    // int[,,] arr = new int[3, 2, 3];
    printArrayIndexes(arr);
}

private static void printArrayIndexes(object arr)
{
    var dimensArr = arr as Array;
    List<int> indexList = new List<int>();
    for (int dimension = 0; dimension < dimensArr.Rank; dimension++)
    {
        indexList.Add(0);
    }
    bool hasItems = true;
    while (hasItems)
    {
        hasItems = false;
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("[{0}]", String.Join(",", indexList)));
        for (int i = 0; i < indexList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (indexList[i] < dimensArr.GetLength(i)) {
                hasItems = true;
                indexList[i]++;
                break;
            } else {
                indexList[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using your sample `int[,] arr = new int[2,2]`:

```
[0,0] [1,0] [2,0] [0,1] [1,1] [2,1] [0,2] [1,2] [2,2]
```

Using any 3D array `int[,,] arr = new int[3,2,3]`:

```
[0,0,0] [1,0,0] [2,0,0] [3,0,0] [0,1,0] [1,1,0] [2,1,0] [3,1,0]
[0,2,0] [1,2,0] [2,2,0] [3,2,0] [0,0,1] [1,0,1] [2,0,1] [3,0,1]
[0,1,1] [1,1,1] [2,1,1] [3,1,1] [0,2,1] [1,2,1] [2,2,1] [3,2,1]
[0,0,2] [1,0,2] [2,0,2] [3,0,2] [0,1,2] [1,1,2] [2,1,2] [3,1,2]
[0,2,2] [1,2,2] [2,2,2] [3,2,2] [0,0,3] [1,0,3] [2,0,3] [3,0,3]
[0,1,3] [1,1,3] [2,1,3] [3,1,3] [0,2,3] [1,2,3] [2,2,3] [3,2,3]
```

So you can use 1D, 2D, 3D, 4D arrays...

Answer (score 1):

You can make it yourselves something like this:

```
void IndexPermutations(int range1, int range2)
{
  for(int i=0; i<range1; i++)
  {
   for(int j=0; j<range2; j++)
   {
    Console.WriteLine("[{0},{1}]",i,j);
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is only one dimension...

Comment: So we have to do his whole homework?

Comment: no, we don't have to

Comment: That's not a homework. But your solution is only for two dimension arrays. Writing such an solution for bigger arrays this way is impossible. That's why I'm not asking for solution. I'm asking for library or any way to do this in c#.

Comment: @107MP And asking for libraries is also not allowed. Still, this is not that difficult of a task that you can't write your own method.

Comment: @krillgar Anyway thanks for the information. I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive solution.

```
public void IndexPermutations(int dimensionSize, int minValue, int maxValue, Action<List<int>> action)
{
    IndexPermutationsInternal(dimensionSize, minValue, maxValue, action, new List<int>());
}

private void IndexPermutationsInternal(
    int dimensionSize,
    int minValue,
    int maxValue,
    Action<List<int>> action,
    List<int> current)
{
    if (dimensionSize == current.Count)
    {
        action(current);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = minValue; i <= maxValue; i++)
        {
            current.Add(i);
            IndexPermutationsInternal(dimensionSize, minValue, maxValue, action, current);
            current.RemoveAt(current.Count - 1);
        }
    }
}
```